# Boost asio http client - don't receive status line, get content directly instead

Tags: c++, http, httpclient, boost-asio

I'm using this example code for an HTTP client http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/cpp03/http/client/sync_client.cpp with boost 1.52 on Mac OSX 10.8 - compiling with clang (Apple clang 4.1).

When running this example program with the arguments sync_client www.boost.org /LICENSE_1_0.txt\n , I get the following output:

```
Exception: read_until: End of file
```

I debugged into the code and found the exception is thrown here:

```
// Read the response status line. ...
boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");
```

Further debugging into the read_until function revealed that the streambuffer was containing the following text before encountering the EOF:

```
Boost Software License - Version 1.0 - August 17th, 2003

Permission is hereby granted, free of charge, to any person or organization ...
```

As you can see, the streambuf at this time contained the CONTENT to be downloaded over HTTP, instead of the HTTP status line the client was expecting. As the server closes the connection after transmitting the whole file, naturally the read terminates with an EOF.

Question: Why am I getting the content instead of the response line here - what is wrong with the example code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I found the problem using Wireshark and noticed my HTTP request was broken.

The problem was I sent an extra \n after the path, because I copied it from the default parameters.

Comment: I've had the same exception in the same place, but with slightly different streambuf contents when I tried to connect to a server which failed to send CR+LF as HTTP requires. Per general guidelines, be liberal in what you accept and conservative in what you send. `read_until(... "\r\n")` is not that liberal and fails to tolerate a common HTTP implementation error.